# Regex for whitespace or quoted separed words to List

Tags: c#, regex

In C# I Need a RegEx for a search bar control.
The rule is:

- Case insensitive.
- Trim unuseful whitespaces.
- Words are separed with whitespaces.
- Whitespaces between two double quotes (") acts like a valid character to search and not like a separator.

I tried this:

```
"[\w]+|\"([\w\s])+\""
```

---

So if I enter this string:

```
"Jo Ka \"Vid Whi\""
```

I should get this list:

```
{
 "jo", 
 "ka",
 "vid whi"
}
```

That after searching it should match:
***JO**hn Smith, Ma**KA** Alband, **KA**ren Snow* and *Da**VID** **WHI**te*. And not *WHItney Stars*.

But after using ReGex.Match() I get

```
{
 "jo", 
 "ka",
 "\"vid", 
 "whi",
 "\""
}
```

---

If I enter:

```
"Jo  Whi               \"Ka \""
```

I should get

```
{
 "jo", 
 "whi",
 "ka "
}
```

That should match:
_**JO**hn Smith, *David **WHI**te*, ***WHI**tney Stars* and _Ma**KA** Alband. But not *KAren Snow*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
  List<string> result = new List<string>();
  var testString = "Jo Ka \"Vid Whi\"";

  var regex = new Regex("\"[^\"]+\"");
  var matches = regex.Matches(testString);
  // Remove matched string inside quotes and trim possible spaces
  testString = regex.Replace(testString, "").Trim();
  // Add all strings sorrounded by quotes and trim quotes
  foreach (Match match in matches) result.Add(match.Value.Trim('"'));
  // Add rest of strings, which were separated by space
  result.AddRange(testString.Split(' ').Select(s => s.Trim()));
}
```

It's more robust than huge regex and in first uses small, simple regex :)

Comment: I was thinking about this but I'm not sure if this is a good programming practice

Comment: @evilpixi I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be :) Bad programming practice is aiming for short and highly complicated solutions rather than simple ones , but less concise :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`Regex.Split(str,"(?<!\"[^\"\s]+)\s+(?![^\"\s]+\")").Split(s => s.Trim('"');`

Example:

check the `Split List` Tab of this [link](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%22%5CS%2B%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F!%5CS%2B%22%29&i=Jo%20Ka%20%22Vid%20Whi%22%0D%0AJo%20%20Whi%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Ka%20%22)

Comment: almost correct, but I also need the quotes not matched

Comment: It doesn't work on [this data](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F<!"%5CS%2B%29%5Cs%2B%28%3F!%5CS%2B"%29&i=Jo%20Ka%20"Vid%20Whi"%0D%0AJo%20%20Whi%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20"Ka%20")

Comment: @evilpixi: see my update, just use `Trim()` to remove the `"`